# Upgrade scala to "2.10.3" but my jar file only display "2.10"

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I do specify scalaVersion := "2.10.3" in my build.sbt, but after ./sbt package I got my package as myapp_**2.10**-1.0.0.jar.

Doesn't it suppose to be myapp_**2.10.3**-1.0.0.jar ??

Is there any parameter I need to change as well ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because all 2.10.X artifacts are (should be) binary compatible. That's why the minor version isn't included in the artifact name. It shouldn't matter.

I couldn't find an official reference for what I said above, just this post by Martin Odersky: [Binary compatibility: status and outlook](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9346)